# Adding an element of type P[String] in ListBuffer[P[Any]]

Tags: scala

I have this scenario

```
  trait P[T] {
    val attr: T
  }

  val p = new P[String] {
    override val attr: String = "Hello"
  }

  val list = new ListBuffer[P[Any]]
  list += p
```

On `list += p` compiler complains that P[Any] doesn't match with P[String]. How can I create a ListBuffer which could save P of any type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an existential type:

```
val list = new ListBuffer[P[_]]
```